# Spring Data DynamoDb Integration with Spring Boot(java.lang.AbstractMethodError: createPersistentProperty)

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

We were working on the Integration of the Dynamo Db with our Spring Boot Project (maven based project) so as to deploy it as a lambda project which can access data over dynamo db and render it to our static website .After configuring the repos and the POJOS for our project we did mvn clean install and found the following issue that occurred during the build .

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: **Error creating bean with name 'MyInteractivesFunction': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'MyClientDetailsRepository'**;
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Error creating bean with name 'MyClientDetailsRepository': Invocation of init method failed**;
>
> nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.createPersistentProperty(Lorg/springframework/data/mapping/model/Property;Lorg/springframework/data/mapping/model/MutablePersistentEntity;Lorg/springframework/data/mapping/model/SimpleTypeHolder;)Lorg/springframework/data/mapping/PersistentProperty;

It seems that the issue was in mapping the POJO properties with the columns but we created another dummy project separately and it worked there. Need a solution for it.

Comment: Did You find a solution for it? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @KshitizSharma  Kindly refer the below explanation.Please do check the jar version and it should work for you

Answer (score 0):

After lots of searching and applying various ways we found what actually was the real cause of problem was jars incompatibility. Our Spring boot version was based on 2.0.3 and the spring data dynamodb version was 4.5.0 which dont work well with each other.Hence , we found a link that very sweetly describes the issue :
https://derjust.github.io/spring-data-dynamodb/ , So we changed the spring data dynamodb version to 5.0.4 and it worked like a charm we were able to retrieve results from Dynamo Db.